# Не происходит добавление элемента в multiselect.

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь реализовать фильтр на jQuery. Собственно всё работает, да кроме записи выбранных критериев в указанный параграф. Что собственно не так? Буду благодарен за помощь.

```js
$(".filterDropdown dt a").on('click', function() {
  $(".filterDropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
});

$(".filterDropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function() {
  $(".filterDropdown dd ul").hide();
});

function getSelectedValue(id) {
  return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}

$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var $clicked = $(e.target);
  if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("filterDropdown")) $(".filterDropdown dd ul").hide();
});

$('.mutliselect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {

  var title = $(this).closest('.mutliselect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
    title = $(this).val() + ",";

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
    $('.resultSelect').append(html);
    $(".resultFilter").hide();
  } else {
    $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
    var ret = $(".resultFilter");
    $('.filterDropdown dt a').append(ret);

  }
});
```

```css
.filters {
 width: 270px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color:#fff;
 border-right: 1px solid #f7f7f7;
 position: relative;
}

.filterDropdown {
 position: absolute;
 top:30px;
 left: 80px; 
 transform: translate(-50%);
}

.filterDropdown a {
 color:#5795f9;
}

.filterDropdown dd,
.filterDropdown dt {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.filterDropdown ul {
 margin: -1px 0 0 0;
}

.filterDropdown dd {
 position: relative;
}

.filterDropdown a,
.filterDropdown a:visited {
 color: #5795f9;
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.filterDropdown dt a {
 background-color: #fff;
 display: block;
 padding: 8px 20px 5px 10px;
 min-height: 15px;
 line-height: 24px;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 0;
 width: 152px;
 border:1px solid black;
}



.filterDropdown dt a span,
.resultSelect span {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #000;
 padding: 0 6px 2px 0;
}

.filterDropdown dd ul {
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 0;
 color: #5795f9;
 display: none;
 left: 0px;
 padding: 2px 15px 2px 5px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 2px;
 width: 180px;
 border:1px solid black;
 list-style: none;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: auto;
}

.filterDropdown span.value {
 display: none;
}

.filterDropdown dd ul li a {
 padding: 5px;
 display: block;
}

.filterDropdown dd ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #5795f9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl class = "filterDropdown">
    <dt>
     <a href="#">
      <span class = "resultFilter"></span>
      <span class = "resultFilterNew"></span>
      <p class = "resultSelect"></p>
     </a>

     

    </dt>

    <dd>
     <div class = "multiselect">
      <ul>

       <li><input type="checkbox" value="Kyiv">Kyiv</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" value="Kharkiv">Kharkiv</li>
       <li><input type="checkbox" value="Lviv">Lviv</li>

      </ul>
     </div>
    </dd>

   </dl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.mutliselect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {`

тут у вас **mutliselect** вместо **multiselect**

`<div class = "multiselect">` пробелы вокруг `=` лучше убрать